# Refactor Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to refactor my code. My question is: how can I refactor a method that saves data in several tables at the same time?

I think writing this code is essential. On the other hand, it is too long for a controller's method. Can I move some of them to a Model?

I have a `product` that it has some relations such as `Price`, `specials`, `maintenance`, etc.

```php
public function store(AddProductRequest $request)
{
    $shopperId = 1;

    $product = new Product([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'slug' => to_slug_fa($request->title, Product::class),
        'detail' => $request->detail,
        'color_id' => $request->colorId,
        'category_id' => $request->categoryId,
        'img' => $request->img,
        'description' => $request->description,
    ]);

    $category = Category::find($request->categoryId);

    $category->Product()->save($product);

    $code = create_code($request->categoryId, $product['id'], $request->colorId);

    $product->update(['code' => $code]);

    $price = new Price([
        'price' => $request->price,
        'product_id' => $product->id,
    ]);

    $product->price()->save($price);

    $stocks = [];

    foreach ($request->sizeIds as $value) {
        if ($request->quantity[$value] != null) {
            $stocks[] = new Stock([
                'stock' => $request->quantity[$value],
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'size_id' => $value,
                'shopper_id' => $shopperId,
            ]);
        }
    }

    $product->stock()->saveMany($stocks);

    $productAttributes = [];

    foreach ($request->attributeIds as $value) {
        if (isset($request->productAttribute[$value])) {
            $productAttributes[] = new ProductAttribute([
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'attribute_id' => $value,
                'value' => $request->productAttribute[$value],
            ]);
        }
    }

    $product->ProductAttribute()->saveMany($productAttributes);

    $productDetail = [];

    foreach ($request->productDetails as $value) {
        if (isset($value)) {
            $productDetail[] = new ProductDetail([
                'description' => $value,
                'parent_id' => $product->id,
            ]);
        }
    }

    $product->ProductDetail()->saveMany($productDetail);

    $product_Maintenance = [];

    foreach ($request->productMaintenance as $value) {
        if (isset($value)) {
            $product_Maintenance[] = new ProductMaintenance([
                'description' => $value,
                'parent_id' => $product->id,
            ]);
        }
    }

    $product->ProductMaintenance()->saveMany($product_Maintenance);

    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some lines that are redundant (serve no purpose) depending on your fillable attributes.

If `category_id` is a fillable attribute in `Product`, then these lines don't do anything, because the category_id will already be set

```php
    $category = Category::find($request->categoryId);

    $category->Product()->save($product);
```

This could be moved to a `created/saved` event I think.

```
    $code = create_code($request->categoryId, $product['id'], $request->colorId);

    $product->update(['code' => $code]);
```

If `product_id` is a fillable attribute in `Price`, then won't do anything because you're already setting the `product_id` a couple of lines before that.

```
    $product->price()->save($price);
```

Same deal with this

```
    $product->stock()->saveMany($stocks);
    $product->ProductAttribute()->saveMany($productAttributes);
    $product->ProductMaintenance()->saveMany($product_Maintenance);
```

Whenever you have something like

```php
$results = []
foreach ($something as $item) {
    $result[] = ...;
}
```

It can be replaced by a `map` operation. Whether you decide that adds complexity or not is up to you.

If I had to rewrite it, I'd use collection methods to handle all the looping parts, inline the `code` in Product, and use `create` whenever possible. This means all models must have their `$fillable` or `$guarded` properties set.

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($product) {
            // you might need to inline the create_code function here
            $product->code = create_code($product->category_id, $product->id, $product->color_id); 
            $product->save();
        });
    }
}
```

```php
public function store(AddProductRequest $request)
{
    $shopperId = 1;

    $product = Product::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'slug' => to_slug_fa($request->title, Product::class),
        'detail' => $request->detail,
        'color_id' => $request->colorId,
        'category_id' => $request->categoryId,
        'img' => $request->img,
        'description' => $request->description,
    ]);
    
    $product->price()->create(['price' => $request->price]);

    collect($request->sizeIds)
        ->filter(fn($value) => $request->quantity[$value] != null);
        ->map(fn($value) => [
            'stock' => $request->quantity[$value],
            'size_id' => $value,
            'shopper_id' => $shopperId,
        ])
        ->each(fn($value) => $product->stock()->create($value));

    collect($request->attributeIds)
        ->filter(fn($value) => isset($request->productAttribute[$value]))
        ->map(fn($value) => [
            'attribute_id' => $value,
            'value' => $request->productAttribute[$value],
        ])
        ->each(fn($value) => $product->ProductAttribute()->create($value));

    collect($request->productDetails)
        ->filter(fn($value) => isset($value)) // or just ->filter()
        ->map(fn($value) => [
            'description' => $value,
        ])
        ->each(fn($value) => $product->ProductDetail()->create($value));

    collect($request->productMaintenance)
        ->filter(fn($value) => isset($value)) // or just ->filter()
        ->map(fn($value) => [
            'description' => $value,
        ])
        ->each(fn($value) => $product->ProductMaintenance()->create($value));

    return back();
}
```

As an aside. I do not think this is a bloated method. You see exactly what is happening. You're saving a Product and its relationships. You can move logic around if you want, or even split it into different methods.

```php
public function store(AddProductRequest $request)
{
    $shopperId = 1;

    $product = Product::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'slug' => to_slug_fa($request->title, Product::class),
        'detail' => $request->detail,
        'color_id' => $request->colorId,
        'category_id' => $request->categoryId,
        'img' => $request->img,
        'description' => $request->description,
    ]);
    
    $this->storePrice($product, $request);
    $this->storeStocks($product, $request, $shopperId);
    $this->storeProductAttributes($product, $request);
    $this->storeProductDetails($product, $request);
    $this->storeProductMaintenances($product, $request);

    return back();
}

private function storePrice(Product $product, $request)
{
    $product->price()->create(['price' => $request->price]);
}

private function storeStocks(Product $product, $request, $shopperId);
{
    collect($request->sizeIds)
        ->filter(fn($value) => $request->quantity[$value] != null);
        ->map(fn($value) => [
            'stock' => $request->quantity[$value],
            'size_id' => $value,
            'shopper_id' => $shopperId,
        ])
        ->each(fn($value) => $product->stock()->create($value));
}

private function storeProductAttributes(Product $product, $request);
{
    collect($request->attributeIds)
        ->filter(fn($value) => isset($request->productAttribute[$value]))
        ->map(fn($value) => [
            'attribute_id' => $value,
            'value' => $request->productAttribute[$value],
        ])
        ->each(fn($value) => $product->ProductAttribute()->create($value));
}

private function storeProductDetails(Product $product, $request);
{
    collect($request->productDetails)
        ->filter(fn($value) => isset($value)) // or just ->filter()
        ->map(fn($value) => [
            'description' => $value,
        ])
        ->each(fn($value) => $product->ProductDetail()->create($value));
}

private function storeProductMaintenances(Product $product, $request)
{
    collect($request->productMaintenance)
        ->filter(fn($value) => isset($value)) // or just ->filter()
        ->map(fn($value) => [
            'description' => $value,
        ])
        ->each(fn($value) => $product->ProductMaintenance()->create($value));
}
```

Or create a special class that will do everything™ like an `App\Action\CreateProduct` class

```php
public function store(AddProductRequest $request)
{
    new CreateProduct($request->validated());

    return back();
}
```

But that won't make the logic itself any simpler.

Comment: I just wanted to day that that was a fantastic and thorough answer. Wow. My only comment is that  you could probably replace ->filter(fn($value) => isset($value)) with ->filter()

Comment: At the end of the day it's still a bit subjective. Thanks for the tip by the way! I didn't know filter could be used with no Closures. I'll add that as a comment

Comment: This answer will help lot of people. Good work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete guidance. This is definitely very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, and it's better actually to do so, you can take this rule always :keep your controller thin your model fat and your view dumb..

Answer (score 0):

It is a subjective question. But your question is still legitimate. The task of a controller is only to accept the request, to check whether the request is valid and to delegate further. And from now on it depends on your architecture and your taste. In your case, I would think that the logic of storing a model and its relationships can be put into a service. Here you can check your code if you can make functions out of code parts that can be used multiple times. It's enough to start with. Later on you'll probably realize by yourself what's important.